# Get integer part of number

Tags: t-sql

So I have a table with numbers in decimals, say

```
id    value
2323   2.43
4954  63.98
```

And I would like to get

```
id    value
2323      2
4954     63
```

Is there a simple function in T-SQL to do that?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
SELECT FLOOR(value)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx

FLOOR returns the largest integer less than or equal to the specified numeric expression.

Comment: It is important to clarify, that although this response does satisfy the request with the sample data provided, that the Floor function reacts differently with negative values. 

Floor(123.45) would return 123
but
Floor(-123.45) would return 124

Comment: Actually, it would return -124, the largest integer less than or equal to the specified numeric expression. :)

Comment: A good way to understand that it does work the same for negative and positive values is to look at its graph here : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloorFunction.html

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are OK with truncation of the decimal part you can do:
`SELECT Id, CAST(value AS INT) INTO IntegerTable FROM NumericTable`

Answer (score 2):

FLOOR,CAST... do not return integer part with negative numbers, a solution is to define an internal procedure for the integer part:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS INTEGER_PART//

CREATE FUNCTION INTEGER_PART(n DOUBLE)

RETURNS INTEGER


DETERMINISTIC 

BEGIN

IF (n >= 0) THEN RETURN FLOOR(n);
            ELSE RETURN CEILING(n);      
END IF;


END
//

MariaDB [sidonieDE]> SELECT INTEGER_PART(3.7);
+-------------------+
| INTEGER_PART(3.7) |
+-------------------+
|                 3 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sidonieDE]> SELECT INTEGER_PART(-3.7);
+--------------------+
| INTEGER_PART(-3.7) |
+--------------------+
|                 -3 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

after you can use the procedure in a query like that:

```
 SELECT INTEGER_PART(value) FROM table;
```

if you do not want to define an internal procedure in the database you can put an IF  in a query like that:

```
 select if(value < 0,CEILING(value),FLOOR(value)) from table ;
```